# Select2 with Ajax is not sending request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 version 4.0.0 and trying to load a remote JSON from a PHP script that returns the already formated data that I need. The problem is that the forces of the darkness are making something, because I just can't send the request, there is no error, but there is no request sent, it just stays so quiet as a devil that I'm almost crying!

I'm using LiveScript and Jade as alternatives to JavaScript and HTML, but I'll translate'em here.

First, my markup defines the selectable field:

```
<select id="satan-hates-me"></select>
```

Then, I'm able to make it look like a selectable element:

```
 $("#satan-hates-me").select2({
    placeholder: "Hail",
    minimumInputLength: 1,
    ajax: { // Here that bad things happen, I mean, don't happen
      url: "http://localhost/os/backend/TestServiceOrder.php?req=getEquipments",
      dataType: "json",
      type: "GET",
      quietMillis: 50,
      data: function(term) { return { term: term } },
      results: function(data) { return data; }
    }
  });
```

I'm performing this wrapped in a load function, after page loading, it looks like a selectable, but sends no requests, and the script returns me **exactly** the required format, as example:

```
[{id: 1, text: "Sadness"}, {id: 2, text: "Depression"}]
```

And here goes. I can design compilers but I can't in the world make a plugin work with Ajax! Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Ah, what a perfect day to die!

Comment: `results` is now `processResults` in 4.0.0. And have you confirmed that no requests are sent within your developer tools, or is this based on logging within `results`?

Comment: Oh, yeah, I did. In the end, I solved it by an external request and by using async programming with monads to deal with computations that may fail.

Comment: That the lords of monads and async programming forgive me by doing workarounds with monads.

Comment: still no solution!!?? been trying to resolve it since last 4 hours, no luck

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Finally resolved the issue.

> `<input>` is not supported in select2 v4

.You have to use `<select>` element instead

Comment: Thank you. This resolved a similar issue for me (using simple_form, specified `as: :select` fixed it)

Answer (score 4):

In my case, it was a general select2-call of .select2-Elements in the footer of all my templates:

```
$('.select2').select2();
```

Event though my select for the Ajax-Request didn't have that class at all (I called it via an id), I had to change the above to

```
$('select.select2').select2({theme: 'classic'});
```

I guess select2() creates several elements with the class .select2, so that might interfere

Comment: This answer should be upvoted since there is no easy way to know that `select2` class must be avoided