# Ajax Select2 don't send request

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, jquery-select2

I'm using Select2 4.0.3 to choose many fields. When I'm using static data, it's work perfectly. But when I use ajax, it's don't send any request to my server. Others ajax works. There isn't erros on browser console. My problem is very similar with this topic [Select2 with Ajax is not sending request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30310060/select2-with-ajax-is-not-sending-request), but any answer works for me. I'm using python2.7 and flask.

**JavaScript**

```js
$('#machine').select2({                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
    multiple: true,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
    ajax: {                                                                                                                                                               
        url: '/example/api/',                                                                                                                                                         
        dataType: "json",                                                                                                                                                 
        type: "GET",                                                                                                                                                      
        data: function (params) {                                                                                                                                         

            var queryParameters = {                                                                                                                                       
                term: params.term                                                                                                                                         
            }                                                                                                                                                             
            return queryParameters;                                                                                                                                       
        },                                                                                                                                                                
        processResults: function (data) {                                                                                                                                 
            return {                                                                                                                                                      
                results: $.map(data, function (item) {                                                                                                                    
                    return {                                                                                                                                              
                        text: item.tag_value,
                        id: item.tag_id
                    }                    
                })           
            };                                      
        }                     
    }
});
```

**Html**

```html
<select id="machine" class="form-control select2" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Escolhe os terminais" style="width: 100%;">

  <option value="172.26.130.77">RJ0219AT007 (IP: 172.26.130.77)</option>
  <option value="172.26.130.77">RJ0219AT007 (IP: 172.26.130.77)</option>
  <option id='teste' value="172.26.130.77">RJ0219AT007 (IP: 172.26.130.77)</option>
</select>
```

**Python2.7**

```
@manutencao.route('/example/api/', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def show_machines():
    print 'DOOOOOOOOOOOONT WOOOOOOOOOOOORK!!!!'
    return jsonify({'data':'WOOORK, PLS!!'})
```

No erros, no logs of requests on server and don't works. Can somebody help me, please?

Comment: Did you find sollution?